# render a component on button click React ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to open/render/show a component on button click. I'm trying to do this by changing state but unable to do so.

I want to render  component on button click. The state gets changed but the component doesn't render.

```
    export default class NewNav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      login: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.state.login = true;
    }

  render() {

    const style = {
      margin: 12
    };

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>

        <div className="top-bar">
          <div className="top-bar-left">
            <ul className="menu">
              <li>
                <RaisedButton
                  label="Sign Up"
                  style={style}
                  primary={false}
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                  labelColor="#FFF"
                  backgroundColor="#00E676"/>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="top-bar-right">

            <ul className="menu">

              <li>
                <RaisedButton
                  label="Log In"
                  primary={true}
                  className="btnLogin"
                  backgroundColor="#3AAA35"></RaisedButton>

              </li>

              <li>
                <RaisedButton
                  label="Sign Up"
                  primary={false}
                  labelColor="#FFF"
                  backgroundColor="#00E676"/>

              </li>

            </ul>
            {this.state.login
              ? <FirstPage/>
              : null
}

          </div>

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `state` directly, use `setState` method. Otherwise react is not aware of state change and will not re-render component.

So instead of this:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    this.state.login = true;
  }
```

use this:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({login: true});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is changing the state without letting React knowing it:
according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) you an see that

`setState()`

> Performs a shallow merge of nextState
>   into current state. This is the primary method you use to trigger UI
>   updates from event handlers and server request callbacks.

The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object containing keys to update.

Here is the simple object usage:

```
this.setState({mykey: 'my new value'});
```

So in your case you are supposed to update your state using something like this:

```
 handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({login: true});   
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I realized the mistake. I was updating the state the wrong way